# Use expect script from Vagrantfile for provisioning - problem with non existing file during execution

Tags: bash, shell-script, expect, vagrant

Is is possible to use expect script from Vagrantfile for provisioning?

It looks like file inside the installOracle.exp script is not there at the proper moment (see error log):

```
spawn "/var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracleDatabase.sh"
```

File is there!:)

```
[vagrant@wemdbc01 ~]$ ls -la /var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracleDatabase.sh
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 vagrant vagrant 541 May 25 08:43 /var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracleDatabase.sh
```

Related part of my Vagrantfile:

```
  [...]
  db.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  db.vm.synced_folder "C:/Installers", "/var/wminst"
  db.vm.provision :shell, :inline  => "yum -y install expect"
  db.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "expect /var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracle.exp" 
end
```

installOracle.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set timeout 20

spawn "/var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracleDatabase.sh"

expect "replace Disk1/upgrade/gen_inst.sql?" { send "N\r" }
expect "Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express" { send "\r" }
expect "Specify a port that will be used for the database listener" { send "\r" }
expect "initial configuration:" { send "root\r" }
expect "Confirm the password:" { send "root\r" }
expect "Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot" { send "y\r" }
expect eof
expect eof
expect "Installation completed successfully." { send "\r" }
expect eof
```

Error:

```
==> wemdbc01: Running provisioner: shell...
    wemdbc01: Running: inline script
==> wemdbc01: spawn /var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracleDatabase.sh
==> wemdbc01: couldn't execute "/var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracleDatabase.sh": no such file or directory
==> wemdbc01:     while executing
==> wemdbc01: "spawn "/var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracleDatabase.sh""
==> wemdbc01:     (file "/var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracle.exp" line 5)
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Edit 1:
Changed:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Error log now:

```
==> wemdbc01: Running provisioner: shell...
    wemdbc01: Running: inline script
==> wemdbc01: spawn /var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracleDatabase.sh
: No such file or directory bash
==> wemdbc01: expect: spawn id exp5 not open
==> wemdbc01:     while executing
==> wemdbc01: "expect "Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express" { send "\r" }"
==> wemdbc01:     (file "/var/wminst/vm_provision/oracle_installer/installOracle.exp" line 8)
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Comment: Does the script specify a valid interpreter on the first line with `#!`?

Comment: Good suggestion. Another error now.

Comment: Hmm... It looks like you don't have `bash` installed, or it is installed in an unusual location which is not in your `$PATH`. Is the script really a `bash` script? If not, try `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: I'm on Windows - does it matter? 
When connected in to the VM and run scripts manually - they are running just fine.

Comment: The fact that the VM is running on Windows should not matter. I currently unsure as to why it won't work for you, especially as you say that it works well if you run the script manually. There is something about running it with Vagrant that modifies something that I do not understand.

Comment: Wow, Windows actually did matter... 
CRLF -> LF line endings were the source of the problem...jeeez

Case closed I think.

Comment: Ah, yes, if the script was written on Windows, that may well cause issues. The fact that the VM is running on Windows in _not_ an issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic script was produced on Windows, which meant that it had DOS newlines.  This caused the script to fail executing on the Unix VM.

The fact that the VM is running on Windows is not an issue though.